# OCaml |> operator

Tags: ocaml

Could someone explain what the |> operator does? This code was taken from the reference [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html):

```
let m = PairsMap.(empty |> add (0,1) "hello" |> add (1,0) "world")
```

I can see what it does, but I wouldn't know how to apply the |> operator otherwise.

For that matter, I have no idea what the Module.() syntax is doing either. An explanation on that would be nice too.

Comment: See [Prefix and Infix Operator](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/variables-and-functions.html#scrollNav-2-4) of [Real World OCaml 2nd ed](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/) for an excellent explanation and examples, where `|>`, the *reverse application operator*, is contrasted with `@@`, the *application operator*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Module.(e)` is equivalent to `let open Module in e`. It is a shorthand syntax to introduce things in scope.

The operator `|>` is defined in module `Pervasives` as `let (|>) x f = f x`. (In fact, it is defined as an external primitive, easier to compile. This is unimportant here.) It is the *reverse application* function, that makes it easier to chain successive calls. Without it, you would need to write

```
let m = PairsMap.(add (1,0) "world" (add (0,1) "hello" empty))
```

that requires more parentheses.

Comment: To address the specific example that the OP had, it's worth also adding that |> is left associative

Comment: also called "natural application"/"natural composition" . aka mathematics from left to right, the usual latin way. In mathematics notation, natural composition is written "f;g" (and it's the composition in the opposite category)

Answer (score 23):

The `|>` operator looks like the `|` in bash.

The basic idea is that

```
e |> f = f e
```

It is a way to write your applications in the order of execution.

As an exemple you could use it (I don't particularly think you should though) to avoid lets:

```
12 |> fun x -> e
```

instead of

```
let x = 12 in e
```

---

For the `Module.()` thing, it is to use a specific function of a given module.

You probably have seen `List.map` before.
You could of course use `open List` and then only refer to the function with `map`. But if you also `open Array` afterwards, `map` is now referring to `Array.map` so you need to use `List.map`.

Answer (score 11):

The `|>` operator represents reverse function application. It sounds complicated but it just means you can put the function (and maybe a few extra parameters) *after* the value you want to apply it to. This lets you build up something that looks like a Unix pipeline:

```
# let ( |> ) x f = f x;;
val ( |> ) : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
# 0.0 |> sin |> exp;;
- : float = 1.
```

The notation `Module.(expr)` is used to open the module temporarily for the one expression. In other words, you can use names from the module directly in the expression, without having to prefix the module name.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very simple and straightforward explanation.